# Which value changed in Child_changed firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My function is listening if any value of **users** is changing. But I want it to be more specific to trigger only if specific value is changed.

For example, I want it to trigger if only **phone** is changed (do not trigger if anything except phone is changed).

Current code is below:

```
var usersref = firebase.database().ref('users');
usersref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
   var userid = snapshot.key;
   var user = snapshot.val();
   console.log("The updated user name is " + user.name);
});
```

If phone of user is changed, it should trigger. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create another root node called `/user-phones`, and update the corresponding user's phone number there and in their profile, or you could use Cloud Functions to fan-out the changes made to `/users/$uid/phone` to `/user-phones/$uid/phone` automatically.

Now instead of listening for `child_changed` on `/users`, you listen to `/user-phones` which will only trigger when a user changes their phone number.

Comment: Great answer Callam!